# Looking for an SF story where Lebanon was the UN's petri dish for war

Tags: story-identification, warfare

This story is probably 30 years old. as best I recall, the UN has determined to not work towards eliminating internal strife in Lebanon (which arguably it could do), because they felt it was better to let the civil war continue as a way to know how to contain such wars and thereby prevent the equivalent from happening anywhere else. so Lebanon is permanently sacrificed to the UN's protection of the "greater good".

Comment: In what way was this story sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: Arguably the UN cannot eliminate internal strife, and is the cause of much strife in the middle east.  Economist - Why the United Nations cannot end wars in the Arab world etc

Comment: @jwodder Because ["liquid war"](https://www.globalresearch.ca/globalistan-how-the-globalized-world-is-dissolving-into-liquid-war-by-pepe-escobar/5265) is the new normal, it is not contained at all and the UN is AWOL on all serious issues in the real world?

Comment: @jwodder it takes place in a fictional future in which war has been eliminated except for the "Petri dish".

Comment: @OrganicMarble  -- we interpreted jwodder's comment differently; I wonder which he meant.  A question about whether this is sf/fantasy (and thus relevant to this site)? (which you answered) or, a somewhat sarcastic comment on current events (as I read it)?

Answer (score 13):

This is the 1989 story *War Fever* by J. G. Ballard.

In the future the world is at peace, but the UN uses Beirut as a 'Petri dish' allowing war to flourish there and be studied, as the UN allowed smallpox to survive in a small third-world country. (**I don't know whether or not this is true about smallpox, but the claim is made in the story.**)

The Internet Speculative Fiction Database link: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48153

Here is the relevant conversation from the story.

> “Don’t worry, Ryan, I’ll explain it all to you. Tell me first,
> though—have you ever heard of a disease called smallpox?”
>
> “It was some sort of terrible fever. It doesn’t exist any more.”
>
> “That’s true—almost. Fifty years ago the World Health Organization launched a huge campaign to eliminate smallpox, one of the
> worst diseases mankind has ever known, a real killer that destroyed
> tens of millions of lives. There was a global program of vaccination,
> involving doctors and governments in every country. Together they
> finally wiped it from the face of the earth.”
>
> “I’m glad, doctor—if only we could do the same for war.”
>
> “Well, in a real sense we have, Ryan—almost. In the case of
> smallpox, people can now travel freely all over the world. The virus
> does survive in ancient graves and cemeteries, but if by some freak
> chance the disease appears again there are supplies of vaccine to
> protect people and stamp it out.”
>
> Dr. Edwards detached the magazine from Ryan’s rifle and
> weighed it in his hands, showing an easy familiarity with the weapon
> that Ryan had never seen before. Aware of Ryan’s surprise, he
> smiled wanly at the young man, like a headmaster still attached to a
> delinquent pupil.
>
> “Left to itself, the smallpox virus is constantly mutating. We
> have to make sure that our supplies of vaccine are up-to-date. So
> WHO was careful never to completely abolish the disease. It deliberately allowed smallpox to flourish in a remote corner of a small
> third-world country, so that it could keep an eye on how the virus
> was evolving. Sadly, a few people went on dying, and are still dying
> to this day. But it’s worth it for the rest of the world. That way we'll
> always be ready if there’s an outbreak of the disease.”
>
> Ryan stared through the plastic windows at the wall map of
> Beirut and the TV monitors with their scenes of smoke and gunfire.
> The Hilton was burning again.
>
> “And Beirut, doctor? Here you're keeping an eye on another
> virus?”
>
> “That’s right, Ryan. The virus of war. Or, if you like, the martial
> spirit. Not a physical virus, but a psychological one even more
> dangerous than smallpox. The world is at peace, Ryan. There hasn’t
> been a war anywhere for thirty years—there are no armies or air
> forces, and all disputes are settled by negotiation and compromise,
> as they should be. No one would dream of going to war, any more
> than a sane mother would shoot her own children if she was cross
> with them. But we have to protect ourselves against the possibility of
> a mad strain emerging, against the chance that another Hitler or Pol
> Pot might appear.”

Comment: i sure never heard of smallpox being allowed to survive -- it makes no sense since so contagious.

Comment: @releseabe Not only contiagious but horrible too and kills with efficiency (antivaxxers have never heard of it). Samples are left in bioweapons labs: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallpox#Post-eradication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallpox#Post-eradication).

Comment: Best cover for this story on this collection: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?262101 ... I have somehwere in my archive.

Comment: @releseabe I don't know of any case where they've kept it alive in the wild, but there have been some serious debates on whether to keep a sample alive in the labs despite it being declared eradicated as per https://www.newsweek.com/smallpox-eradicated-40-years-ago-us-russia-stocks-virus-1476932

Comment: I actually remember reading an account several years ago, of a worker at a facility who stores biopsy results and tissue specimens, who had a badly stored container open up on him, finding out that it was marked as being from a smallpox victim. After much testing, it was found that the virus was dead in the sample, but imagine if the container had not been properly labeled, the virus was still active enough to infect him, and another outbreak started...

Comment: @releseabe Additionally, viruses only evolve when they infect people. Keep it in vials or vats without any animal cells, and it'll never evolve. (Only mutate and degrade.)

Comment: Sadly, it's unlikely we'll ever get an effort like this again. We got really close with Polio, but it requires more vaccinations, its hotspots tend to be wartorn countries where we can't consistently get personnel to, and a conspiracy theory by the Taliban that has led to a fair number of people in Pakistan thinking vaccinations cover for a sinister plot (sadly, not helped by the CIA getting caught embedded agent in these groups).

Comment: In case you're interested, rinderpest is (AFAIK) the only other widespread virus to be eliminated in the wild. (SARS-Cov-1 was eliminated too, but it never became widespread.) Polio and measles eradication *could* happen in the future, although I agree that we have been consistently overoptimistic (in 2010 there was a goal of eradication by 2015 ...) https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/measles

Comment: you've nailed it, this is exactly the story i remember. Thank you! as for the two remaining smallpox repositories, i remain very concerned about the security of the Russian repository.